# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'resp' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tweepy

This appears to be a very common error with a few different solutions,
[python: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'open' referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623093/python-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-open-referenced-before-assignment)

[Python: Help with UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256056/python-help-with-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Where my question is different is that I don’t have a variable "resp" in the code I am running. Most of the other questions were posted because the poster used the same name for a class and variable or they failed to declare it as a global variable.

The Code

```
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('75VSSMGC4pfUB5u0Zt5G3Q', '2olQeiquDg71uwnGoU2c9e2u3qy2LrKkn2p6KWBIdI')
auth.set_access_token('122095773-cCrYa4FWFoBkx44LES8yeBlt8DTG0jnZivJ79k2J', 'p1Nmp9DaPUIThpTamzIMfdvJu0wgdfxmghdwsSagM')
api = tweepy.API(auth)

print api.rate_limit_status()
#print tweepy.api.rate_limit_status()
```

The Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brendan/Documents/workspace/Tweeter/src/rate_limit.py", line 6, in <module>
    print api.rate_limit_status()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 185, in _call
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 147, in execute
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'resp' referenced before assignment
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upgrade your `tweepy` library.

There was a bug when the request fails that would cause the specific error you see, but that has [since been corrected](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/commit/9a4d1c49a69d0f84a67b5897dc2647148bb7de00). The fix is part of version 1.6 and up.

Comment: Hey Martijn

I was running tweepy-1.7.1-py2.7.egg. i have now upgraded that to tweepy-1.9-py2.7.egg. 

However i think the PythonPath is now broken as its given me an "Unresolved import tweepy" -  
Traceback 
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Comment: "Unresolved import tweepy"? Sounds like PyDev, see [Pydev say, "Unresolved import" error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7281955) the other error means your tweepy is now working, and you are getting a network error.

Comment: Also, create new questions for new problems.